# Installing Ubuntu on HP Envy 15 (Pre installes win 8) is not working

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, live-usb

I've read all other posts related with this topic. But I didn't get correct answer. My laptop is HP-Envy 15 j037tx. I've tried to install Linux OS from USB after I've got it. It wasn't working. So I've found some ways from internet.

1. Use 32 bit version of OS
2. Enable legacy boot on BIOS
3. Format USB in NTFS
4. Use earlier version (I've used 12.04)
5. Disable fast-startup

In the boot device list USB showing is OK. After I select it. It takes me to the black screen with blinking white dash. Not even showing installing menu or Ubuntu logo. When I used Ubuntu 9.10 on live CD it took me to the menu to install or try Ubuntu. As I think there is some problem with Ubuntu version too. I also tried Virtual box. It also worked on 32 bit for Ubuntu and ElementaryOS. But not with 64 bit OS. When I add x64 ISO it give error, like not correct kernel found. I need to install on dual-boot mode.

Is there anyone who can direct me to the correct way?

Comment: This might help if you are still struggling: [http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-laptop-and-netbook-25/can't-boot-into-hp-envy-15-ah150sa-radeon-after-install-4175584667/](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-laptop-and-netbook-25/can't-boot-into-hp-envy-15-ah150sa-radeon-after-install-4175584667/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that your points 1-4 are all the *exact opposite* of what you should have done.

Computers that come pre-installed with Windows 8 or 8.1 almost invariably boot in EFI mode. When installing Ubuntu for dual-booting with a computer that's already booting in EFI mode, it's almost always easiest and best to install Ubuntu in EFI mode. In the case of most modern PCs, that also means installing the 64-bit version of Ubuntu, because EFI ties the OS bit depth to the CPU bit depth more tightly than does BIOS.

To learn how you should have done it, consult one or both of the following pages:

- [My page on EFI-mode Linux installations](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)
- [The Ubuntu community wiki on the same topic](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

An EFI-mode installation need not be a nightmare, but it can quickly become so if you follow bad advice or flounder about randomly. Unfortunately, there is a lot of bad advice on this topic on the Internet. Also unfortunately, what works for one installation often doesn't work for another, because EFI implementations vary widely from one to another. (Some of this variation involves bugs, but some of it is variation that's occurred where the EFI spec is vague about some detail.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.i'll use that method.the steps i mentioned are not in order, i wrote all i got, but you are correct.i also found some distractions on posts.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that I may be a [rare?] case of this method working with which you have originally posted.

I did all of the bullet points except for the first one and it worked like a charm and I struggled for a good day trying to get around this fast-boot crap.
I had win 8 pre-loaded and needed to replace it.

As Rod said, just find what works for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Enable legacy boot and save it. 
Press escape key while booting up. 
It will give options to select bios and boot options. Press f9 for boot options. There you can see your Ubuntu or Linux OS. Select that and continue. There you go.